# Get string from CryptoStream in loop

Tags: c#, encryption, random, cryptography

I am having problems to extract a string from a memory stream. The memory stream is decorated with a crypto stream. It appears, unless I flush the crypto stream, I cannot read anything from the memory stream.

I am trying to generate multiple strings (which will then be parsed to numerical values) within a for-loop. So far I can't read from a memory stream while the crypto stream is still active.

As one can see, I am trying to measure the runtime but the length of my memory stream always appears to be zero. I also need to find an efficient way to get a string from the encrypted byte array which i extract from the memory stream.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesInstance.CreateEncryptor(aesInstance.Key, aesInstance.IV);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

int counter = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
byte[] text;
byte[] num;

watch.Start();
for (int k = 0; k < rounds; k++) {

    text = encoder.GetBytes(counter.ToString());
    cs.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock(); 
    num = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Read(num, 0, (int)num.Length);

    ms.Flush();
    counter++;
}
watch.Stop();
```

Comment: You must comprehend that there are two types of ciphers: block ciphers and stream ciphers. Block ciphers encrypt and decrypt fixed lenghts of data. The final "packet" of data is padded to the required length. So if you use AES, for example, the block size is always 128 bits (16 bytes). Stream ciphers encrypt and decrypt one byte at a time, so they don't require an end padding. There are no stream ciphers in .NET

Comment: CryptoStream buffers data until a packet is full, then it encrypts/decrypts it. The `FlushFinalBlock` forces the `CryptoStream` to pad the current packet to the required length and encrypt it

Comment: So is there a way to use AES as block cipher in C# (from which in can then generate a float or double)?

Comment: AES IS a Block Cypher no matter what language you are using it in.

Comment: @Kevin AES in CTR-mode should be a stream cipher. It isn't supported in .NET. It could be built atop the ECB mode, but I do think it is difficult (see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/is-this-how-to-implement-ctr-around-a-system-that-only-implements-cbc-cfb-cts)

Comment: @user3605638 But I do feel that yours is a XY problem... Explain with some examples what you want to do... it seems you want to encrypt one after the other some strings... How should the "reader" distinguish between the strings? Do you have a separator? Do you want to prepend before the strings the length of the string? For example, you could prepend to each encrypted block (that has the FlushFinalBlock called) the length of the encrypted block. So if the encrypted version of Hello is long 16, you would send 16{16 chars of encrypted string}.

Comment: If you want a Stream cipher, then [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) is very easy to program.  It is obsolescent, so don't use it for real world work.  It is useful for practice and to keep your kid sister from reading stuff (unless she works for the NSA).

Comment: @xanatos I think CTR is pretty easy to program. A lot easier than RC4 anyway, and RC4 has quite a few vulnerabilities to work around. The trickiest part is of course the buffering; even with CTR mode you still have to buffer the encrypted counter, even if you don't have to buffer the plaintext/ciphertext.

Comment: There is of course always the Bouncy Castle C# implementation that contains the `SicBlockCipher` implementation, which already implements CTR mode encryption.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes "easy" as "two hours easy" :-) Added an implementation of CTR mode

Comment: `stream.Read` without checking the return value is a bug, even if it probably cannot be triggered with a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @xanatos Yep, I agree with Codes. I implemented CTR mode itself as well (but it's not validated yet), and although you can at least be sure that your stream has similar properties as the underlying stream (it doesn't block until a full block becomes available) you should not disregard `stream.Read`. In that sense a stream cipher does not fully solve the issue; you have to know the size of the data types and make sure you read just enough data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example based on what I wrote in the comment:

```
var lst = new List<string> {
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar",
    "FooBar",
};

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

var aesInstance = Aes.Create();

foreach (var str in lst)
{
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesInstance.CreateEncryptor(aesInstance.Key, aesInstance.IV);

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(encrypted.Length);
    ms.Write(length, 0, length.Length);
    ms.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
}

ms.Position = 0;

while (ms.Position < ms.Length)
{
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesInstance.CreateDecryptor(aesInstance.Key, aesInstance.IV);

    byte[] length = new byte[4];
    int read = ms.Read(length, 0, length.Length);

    if (read < length.Length)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    int length2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);

    byte[] encrypted = new byte[length2];
    read = ms.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

    if (read < encrypted.Length)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    byte[] decrypted = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: {0} bytes, value: {1}", encrypted.Length, str);
}
```

The length of each encrypted "packet" is prepended as an `Int32` to the packet. If you watch the output, you'll see that for the strings given the length of the packet is always 16 or 32. For longer strings it will go up by 16 at a time (48, 64, 80, 96...). Note that there is a bug with the CBC mode, so you can't correctly `TransformFinalBlock` twice or you'll get an error on decryption. To solve this I'm recreating the `encryptor`/`decryptor` for each string. This will cause equal strings to be encrypted in the same way. So if you encrypt `"Foo"` twice, they will be the same `XXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYY` in the encrypted stream.

**CTR Mode**

As I wrote in the comments, the best thing would be to have a CTR mode. The CTR mode has the advantage that the encrypted stream has the same length as the non-encrypted stream, and the input stream can be encrypted/decrypted one byte at a time. Using these two "characteristics" we can modify the encryption/decryption sample to encrypt/decrypt even the string length. Note that in the `AesCtr` class I've added some tests based on the vectors from http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf, so the implementation should be correct.

```
public class AesManagedCtr : Aes
{
    private AesManaged Aes;

    public AesManagedCtr()
    {
        Aes = new AesManaged();
        Aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    }

    public override byte[] IV
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.IV;
        }
        set
        {
            Aes.IV = value;
        }
    }

    public override byte[] Key
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.Key;
        }
        set
        {
            Aes.Key = value;
        }
    }

    public override int KeySize
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.KeySize;
        }
        set
        {
            Aes.KeySize = value;
        }
    }

    public override CipherMode Mode
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.Mode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != CipherMode.ECB)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException();
            }
        }
    }

    public override PaddingMode Padding
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.Padding;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != PaddingMode.None)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException();
            }
        }
    }

    public override int BlockSize
    {
        get
        {
            return 8;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != 8)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException();
            }
        }
    }

    public override KeySizes[] LegalBlockSizes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { new KeySizes(BlockSize, BlockSize, 0) };
        }
    }

    public override int FeedbackSize
    {
        get
        {
            return Aes.FeedbackSize;
        }
        set
        {
            if (FeedbackSize != Aes.FeedbackSize)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException();
            }
        }
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor()
    {
        // Note that we always use the Aes.CreateEncryptor, even for
        // decrypting, because we only have to "rebuild" the encrypted
        // CTR nonce.
        return CreateEncryptor();
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Note that we always use the Aes.CreateEncryptor, even for
        // decrypting, because we only have to "rebuild" the encrypted
        // CTR nonce.
        return CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor()
    {
        return new StreamCipher(Aes.CreateEncryptor(), IV);
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }

        if (!ValidKeySize(key.Length * 8))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("key");
        }

        if (iv == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");
        }

        if (iv.Length * 8 != BlockSizeValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("iv");
        }

        return new StreamCipher(Aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), iv);
    }

    public override void GenerateIV()
    {
        Aes.GenerateIV();
    }

    public override void GenerateKey()
    {
        Aes.GenerateKey();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Aes.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    protected sealed class StreamCipher : ICryptoTransform
    {
        private ICryptoTransform Transform;

        private byte[] IV;
        private byte[] EncryptedIV = new byte[16];
        private int EncryptedIVOffset = 0;

        public StreamCipher(ICryptoTransform transform, byte[] iv)
        {
            Transform = transform;

            // Note that in this implementation the IV/Nonce and the 
            // Counter described by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29
            // are additioned together in a single IV, that then is
            // incremented by 1 in a "big-endian" mode.
            IV = (byte[])iv.Clone();
            Transform.TransformBlock(IV, 0, IV.Length, EncryptedIV, 0);
        }

        public bool CanReuseTransform
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public int InputBlockSize
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        public int OutputBlockSize
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset)
        {
            int count = Math.Min(inputCount, outputBuffer.Length - outputOffset);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (EncryptedIVOffset == EncryptedIV.Length)
                {
                    IncrementNonceAndResetOffset();
                }

                outputBuffer[outputOffset + i] = (byte)(inputBuffer[inputOffset + i] ^ EncryptedIV[EncryptedIVOffset]);
                EncryptedIVOffset++;
            }

            return count;
        }

        public byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            // This method can be reused. There is no "final block" in
            // CTR mode, because characters are encrypted one by one
            byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[inputCount];
            TransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount, outputBuffer, 0);
            return outputBuffer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Transform != null)
            {
                Transform.Dispose();
                Transform = null;
                IV = null;
                EncryptedIV = null;
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void IncrementNonceAndResetOffset()
        {
            int i = IV.Length - 1;

            do
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    IV[i]++;
                }

                if (IV[i] != 0 || i == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                i--;
            }
            while (true);

            Transform.TransformBlock(IV, 0, IV.Length, EncryptedIV, 0);
            EncryptedIVOffset = 0;
        }
    }

    // A simple string-to-byte[] converter
    private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = byte.Parse(str.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        // Taken from http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf
        // F.5.1 CTR-AES128.Encrypt
        // F.5.2 CTR-AES128.Decrypt 
        // F.5.3 CTR-AES192.Encrypt 
        // F.5.4 CTR-AES192.Decrypt 
        // F.5.5 CTR-AES256.Encrypt
        // F.5.6 CTR-AES256.Decrypt  

        string[] keys = new[]
        {
            // 128 bits
            "2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c",
            // 192 bits
            "8e73b0f7da0e6452c810f32b809079e562f8ead2522c6b7b",
            // 256 bits
            "603deb1015ca71be2b73aef0857d77811f352c073b6108d72d9810a30914dff4",
        };

        string iv = "f0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff";

        string[] plains = new[]
        {
            "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a",
            "ae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51",
            "30c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52ef",
            "f69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710",
        };

        string[][] encrypteds = new[]
        {
            // 128 bits
            new[]
            {
                "874d6191b620e3261bef6864990db6ce",
                "9806f66b7970fdff8617187bb9fffdff",
                "5ae4df3edbd5d35e5b4f09020db03eab",
                "1e031dda2fbe03d1792170a0f3009cee",
            },
            // 192 bits
            new[]
            {
                "1abc932417521ca24f2b0459fe7e6e0b",
                "090339ec0aa6faefd5ccc2c6f4ce8e94",
                "1e36b26bd1ebc670d1bd1d665620abf7",
                "4f78a7f6d29809585a97daec58c6b050",
            },
            // 256 bits
            new[]
            {
                "601ec313775789a5b7a7f504bbf3d228",
                "f443e3ca4d62b59aca84e990cacaf5c5",
                "2b0930daa23de94ce87017ba2d84988d",
                "dfc9c58db67aada613c2dd08457941a6",
            },
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            var aes = new AesManagedCtr();
            aes.Key = GetBytes(keys[i]);
            aes.IV = GetBytes(iv);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} bits", aes.KeySize);

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypt");

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

                var cipher = new byte[16];

                for (int j = 0; j < plains.Length; j++)
                {
                    byte[] plain = GetBytes(plains[j]);
                    encryptor.TransformBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length, cipher, 0);

                    string cipherHex = BitConverter.ToString(cipher).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();

                    if (cipherHex != encrypteds[i][j])
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error encrypting " + j);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(cipherHex);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypt");

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

                var plain = new byte[16];

                for (int j = 0; j < encrypteds[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    byte[] encrypted = GetBytes(encrypteds[i][j]);
                    decryptor.TransformBlock(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length, plain, 0);

                    string plainHex = BitConverter.ToString(plain).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();

                    if (plainHex != plains[j])
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error decrypting " + j);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(plainHex);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
var lst = new List<string> {
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar",
    "FooBar",
};

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

var aesInstance = new AesManagedCtr();

ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesInstance.CreateEncryptor(aesInstance.Key, aesInstance.IV);

foreach (var str in lst)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length);
    byte[] encryptedLength = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(length, 0, length.Length);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    ms.Write(encryptedLength, 0, encryptedLength.Length);
    ms.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
}

ms.Position = 0;

ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesInstance.CreateDecryptor(aesInstance.Key, aesInstance.IV);

while (ms.Position < ms.Length)
{
    byte[] encryptedLength = new byte[4];
    int read = ms.Read(encryptedLength, 0, encryptedLength.Length);

    if (read < encryptedLength.Length)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    byte[] length = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedLength, 0, encryptedLength.Length);

    int length2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);

    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[length2];
    read = ms.Read(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);

    if (read < encryptedBytes.Length)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    byte[] bytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);

    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: {0} bytes, value: {1}", encryptedBytes.Length, str);
}
```

Note the differences with the other example: here we reuse the `encryptor`/`decryptor`, because in this way every "block" is encrypted in a chain, and even if the same string is repeated twice, the encrypted version will be different.

Comment: @user3605638 I've added a CTR mode example using an implementation of the CTR mode. It should be more secure than the way used in the previous example, and the encrypted stream should be shorted

Comment: Nice, I also created a CTR ICryptoTransform. I'll see if we have major differences :)